# crmBillingFormNotValid // Configuration error - unable to process paymentIntent

Tags: civicontribute

La passerelle de paiement STRIPE affiche une erreur de configuration alors qu'elle fonctionnait correctement il y a quelques mois.
-WordPress et toutes les extensions sont à jour
-La console STRIPE : requête API réussie / aucune tentative Whebhocks
nota : je viens d'ajouter via CiviCRM de nouveaux whebhocks sur les end-point ipn/7/ et ipn/8/

Nous association doit lancer un évènement payant et je dois en urgence réparer.

Merci de vos conseils

Comment: log : try to create card element
created new card element
card element found
Firing Event: crmBillingFormReloadComplete
Firing Event: crmStripeBillingFormReloadComplete
clearing submitdontprocess
civicrmStripe: submit handler
civicrmStripe: reCaptcha library not loaded
civicrmStripe: Stripe is the selected payprocessor
CRM.payment: getTotalAmount: 8
handle submit card
getTotalAmount: 8
isRecur is false
Waiting for pre-auth
getTotalAmount: 8
Currency is: EUR
error: Configuration error - unable to process paymentIntent
Firing Event: crmBillingFormNotValid

Comment: I try a lot of thinks without succes. I guess there some misfit beetwen Stripe production (Id =9) and Stripe test (id=10). I have this error in viewer log [CiviCRM STRIPE Exception: Event: charge.succeeded Error: Customer (cus_KDQmWyEMHT6WT9) and payment processor ID don't match (expected: 9, actual: 10)]

Comment: I find an other issue about Whebhock: Log Viewver indicate [Error processing webhook (ID: 11): No such notification: 'evt_3JYztFBBOGbfg7QJ0Hsfcbmq'; a similar object exists in live mode, but a test mode key was used to make this request.] Indeed the Table: civicrm_paymentprocessor_webhook presents 5 lignes with the same event_id (Whebhock event it). I removed the line 11 without any effet - both issue are linked I desesperate to find the wrong parametre